# Combining multiple code description tables

Tags: r

I have 3 data sets that i would like to merge.
The first one is the coded data set:

```
ID   Gender Race
1    0      1
2    1      3
3    1      2
```

The second and third data sets are the code tables with descriptions

```
Code  Gender
0     Female
1     Male
```

and

```
Code  Race
1     White
2     Black
3     Asian
```

I want to see if there is a better way than just doing a ton of merge statements because i have many more variables than these 2 that i need to merge with their descriptions.  I was thinking that a possible for loop or l/sapply would be good for this task.

I want to make it look like:

```
ID   Gender   Race
1    Female   White   
2    Male     Asian 
3    Male     Black
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you want to replace the numeric codes with the text strings? I think factors would be more appropriate here.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i want.  I can read in everything as factors if that helps.

Comment: You could use a similar approach like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list-simultaneously)

Comment: @David: Why not using simple `ifelse` function?

Comment: @Soheil not sure what you mean.

Comment: @David `data$Gender<-ifelse(data$Gender=="0","Female", "Male")`, if he imports columns as character

Answer (score 3):

A little `dplyr` solution might be

```
main = read.csv(textConnection("ID,   Gender, Race
1,   0,      1
2,   1,      3
3,   1,      2"))

gen = read.csv(textConnection("Code,  Gender
0,     Female
1,     Male"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

race = read.csv(textConnection("Code,  Race
1,     White
2,    Black
3,     Asian"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(race) = c("Race", "RaceStr")
colnames(gen) = c("Gender", "GenderStr")

library(dplyr) # install.packages("dplyr")

main %>% 
  inner_join(gen) %>% 
  inner_join(race) %>% 
  select(ID, GenderStr, RaceStr)
```

The approach I'd take is to map the column names of the code description tables to the variable you're trying to make more readable, then just join by the mapping.

You might also need thr `plyr` package if you don't have it.

Comment: thanks for the help, the dplyr package cant seem to be installed though.

Comment: Installing package into ‘/home/cyee/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 891010 bytes (870 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 870 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Error: package ‘Rcpp’ 0.11.2 was found, but >= 0.11.3 is required by ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/home/cyee/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/dplyr’

Comment: Update the package `Rcpp`

Comment: Another common option for reading plain tables as in the OP is `read.table(header=TRUE,text="paste_OP_text")` That way, you don't have to add commas.

Comment: I get these 2 error: 1) `Warning message:
In inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector`

and `Error in tbl_vars(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default`